# How to extract only what after ">" of a regex expression?

Tags: c#, regex, uipath

How do I extract all the numbers after this ">" on my regex expression.

`<sbs-test-2/sba>15`

15 can change like a random number.

Thank you!!!

I tried this way, but doesn't get me much!

`(< tzdxtext>)(\d\d)`

Comment: I don't get what the "15" means.. is that the result you're trying to get? What are some examples of input and expected results?

Comment: is this: `"<sbs-test-2/sba>15"` the entire string? or is it embeded into a longer one? up to now I don't see any real need for regex. Or are you doing this for an educational purpose?

Comment: how about `>(\d{2})` (exactly 2 digits) or `>(\d+)` (more than two digits). If you have other restrictions than just "after >" you need to elaborate

Comment: It looks like you can try `>\d+$` expression

Comment: @AleksAndreev To get the digits for further use, you should use a capturing group

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your quick response!!!!

15 is the result i'm looking for. (15 is just an example, but it's only numbers)

"<`sbs-test-2/sba`>15" this the entire string.

@Aleks Andreev, thank you! >\d+$ works!!!

@derpirscher, @Mong Zhu and @Broots Waymb Thank you! problem solved!

Comment: Please use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans). Text inside `<` and `>` is invisible